# Get page load time in modern SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, pnpjs

I need to run some JS script on each page in modern SharePoint online communication site so I created SPFx extension and added to the site.

One of the things I need to do is to get page loading time (its used to be done with `g_duration` in classic site ), client browser and client IP address. Anybody knows how I can do it in SPFx extension?

I started looking to PnP JS but have not found how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use Page Diagnostics for SharePoint tool, it's a tool to analyze SharePoint Online modern and classic site pages against a pre-defined set of performance criteria. You will see the page load time in this tool.

[Use the Page Diagnostics for SharePoint tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/Enterprise/page-diagnostics-for-spo?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: I need it to a part of my extension, so info captured and dealt with every time user opens any page

Comment: If there is no constant to get the page load time, then we cannot get the accurate load time in the spfx extension, and the extension will not load at the same time as the page.